# R flexdashboard tabset styles

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I am trying to modify some of the styles with CSS for a tabset in flexdashboard.  Here's an example of an RMarkdown file.

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Section
===========================================================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### tab1 

text1

### tab2

text2
```

[image]

I want to change the color of the top of the active tab from blue to something else.

[image]

The closest I can get is changing the color of all tabs and not the top.

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

<style>

.tabset { 
  background-color: #00806E;
}

</style>


Section
===========================================================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### tab1 

text1

### tab2

text2
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
  .nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.active {border-top-color: green}
</style>
```

[image: border top colored green in nav tabs]

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to change that color dynamically based on some computed value?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Interesting - I'm not sure. Would you consider posting that as another question on SO?