# How can I choose colors for labels of flex dashboard tabs in RSTudio?

Tags: r, tabs, flexdashboard

I am using the flex dashboard tool to create a dashboard. The dashboard has a few tabs. I am wondering how I can apply colors to the titles/names/labels of the tabs. Thanks!

The following is the code:

```
---
title: "A Template of Dashboard with Pages and Tabs"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: [ "twitter", "facebook", "menu" ]

---

<style>
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black; 
}

.nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.active {border-top-color: black; }


.tabset { 
  background-color: red;
  border: 10px solid green !important;

}

</style>



## Column {data-width=120}



## Column {data-width=880 .tabset}


### Tab 1



### Tab 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved like so:

````
---
title: "A Template of Dashboard with Pages and Tabs"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: [ "twitter", "facebook", "menu" ]
---

```{css}
/* Set font color of inactive tab to green */
.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs > li > a {
  color: green;
} 

/* Set font color of active tab to red */
.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  color: red;
} 

/* To set color on hover */
.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```


## Column {data-width=120}



## Column {data-width=880 .tabset}


### Tab 1



### Tab 2
````

[image]

Comment: Hi Stefan! Though I have figured it out, I would like to give you a thumb up!

Comment: Hi @SamChang. Thx. As I was a bit late with my answer I already guessed that you figured it out yourself. But at least your question now has an answer which may be useful for others. Best S.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Is this in a css chunk in the RMD, or elsewhere?

Comment: @jzadra You could add it via a css chunk or put it inside a `<style>` tag. I just checked it and it works when opening the rendered HTML in the browser.

Comment: Odd.  I've done a barebones attempt and still no luck: https://pastebin.com/36LcEQZG

Comment: @jzadra Wrong selectors. :D My css codes sets the color for the tabsets while (as far as I get it from your code) want to set the color of the navbar tabs in the header row. Try with `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav` instead of `.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs`

Comment: @stefan doh.  Thank you!

Comment: How can we change that small blue border to another color? Found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602519/r-flexdashboard-tabset-styles